# Tweak to Undo CapsLock when the Shift key is used?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I Had found a tweak long ago that turns the Caps Lock off when the Shift key is used, this tweak only changed a few things in the windows Key Mapping.
No other programs were running or required.

The original tweak was an change of the keyboard mapping in the windows registry. It is important that the CapsLock function remain.

tHE pURPACE iS tO kEEP tHIS fROM hAPPENING.

Does anyone know how to Map the shift key to magically unlocking the Caps lock?

Answer (score 3):

#### Does anyone know how to Map the shift key to magically unlocking the Caps lock?

1. Go to "Control Panel" > "Regional and Language Options" > "Keyboards & Languages" > "Change Keyboard" > "Advanced Key Settings".
2. In the section "To turn off Caps Lock" select "Press the SHIFT key".
3. Click "OK".

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: That's great, and it almost works. The Caps-Lock is undone by the Shift key now, but now the Caps-Lock will not turn off itself by pressing it anymore.  Sometimes the normal functions of the Caps-Lock as a toggle are used in games and such, where the use of the Shift to unlock the Caps would get me killed again :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Registry version, tested in Windows 8.1.) Navigate to this Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout
```

Look at the `Attributes` value. If it's not there, create it as a DWORD. Whether Shift disables Caps Lock is determined by the sixteenth bit of that value. Therefore, adding 65536 (decimal) or `0x10000` (hex) to the current value will do it.

You may need to log off and back on for the change to take effect.

Comment: Note that both this answer and the GUI version cause Hyper-V to always interpret Shift as Caps Lock, which could be a deal-breaker if you use Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Steps:

1. Open **Control Panel**
2. Tap **Clock, Language, and Region**.

[image: Clock, Language, and Region]

3. Choose **Language**.

[image: Language]

4. Open **Advanced settings**.

[image: Advanced settings]

5. Click **Change language bar hot keys**.

[image: Change language bar hot keys]

6. Select the **Press the SHIFT key** Option Under **Advance Key Settings** Tab

[image]

7. Click **OK** & you are done.

**Image Source :** http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/change-key-sequence-in-windows-10.html